# TypeError at /myapp/beds/

Tags: django, python-3.x

get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mat_number'

I am new to programming, please how could I resolve the above TypeError following the details below:

```
class BedsView(View):
    def get_user_details(self, username, mat_number):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('index') 
        userbeds = Userbed.objects.filter(user=user, mat_number=mat_number).order_by(-posted_date)[0]
        form = UserBedsForm({'mat_number':userbeds.mat_number})
        return (user, userbeds,form)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, username, mat_number):
        (user,userbeds,form) = self.get_user_details(username, mat_number)
        return render(request, 'myapp/beds.html', {'userbeds':userbeds, 'selecteduser':user, 'form':form})

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request, username):
        (user, userbeds, form) = self.get_user_details(username, mat_number)
        form = UserBedsForm(request.POST, instance=userbeds)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('beds', user. username)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return render(request, 'myapp/beds.html', {'userbeds':userbeds, 'selecteduser':user, 'form':form})
```

At myapp urls.py,

```
   from django.urls import path
   from myapp import views 
   from myapp.views import BedsView 

   app_name = 'myapp'

   urlpatterns = [
          path('beds/<username>/', BedsView.as_view(), name='beds'), 
   ]
```

At myproject urls.py,

```
  from django.contrib import admin 
  from django.urls import path, include 
  from myapp import views 


   urlpatterns = [
          path(' ', views.index, name='index'), 
          path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
          path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')), 
   ]
```

How do I sort this TypeError, please?...

Comment: In your `post()` method, you still have `self.get_user_details(username)`, without `mat_number`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads:

```
def get_user_details(self, username, mat_number):
# ...
(user, userbeds, form) = self.get_user_details(username)
```

`get_user_details` needs to be called with two parameters: `username` and `mat_number`. You only provided one: `username`. So either provide `mat_number` in the method call or change the method signature.

Comment: Any further help, please.

Comment: Then please update your code in the question (both occurrences of `get_user_details`) and post the stack trace (= full error output). And please make sure the code you post is indented exactly the way you use it (indentation is important in Python).

Comment: It is indented exactly that way.

Comment: TypeError at /myapp/beds/ken/

Comment: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mat_number'

Comment: Request Method: GET

Comment: Django Version: 2.1.5

Comment: Exception Type: TypeError

Comment: Exception Value: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mat_number'

Comment: Exception Location: C:\Users\User\job\mysite\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 21

Comment: It is indented very well in my system.

Comment: But the formatting here is giving me something else.

Comment: Kindly go ahead with the solution(s), please.

Comment: Did you read and act on the comment I made under your question today? One last try: you have to call `self.get_user_details` with the correct number of parameters everywhere you use it. Good luck in your learning!

Comment: Do you mean adding username and mat_number in every self.get_user_details as shown below: self.get_user_details(username, mat_number)?...

Comment: Someone should help me out, please.